# Inverse of Drupal contextual filters?

Tags: views

Does anyone know how to / know if Drupal 7 Views 3 is capable of using the inverse of a contextual filter to display results?

Basically I want to display a result not involving the logged in user ID. I can get the view to display only the data associated with the user ID using the contextual filter. I just want the opposite of it. I have tried using the current user filter and checking no for the particular relationship but was unsuccessful. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Unfortunately no.. This helped but this does not establish the relationship I need. 
The data is in two tables. I basically need query like this:

(the first select grabbing all the nid's available)

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.nid
 FROM node n
  WHERE n.status = '1'
    AND n.type = 'job'
    AND n.nid not in
```

(the second select grabbing all the nid's that are associated to a specific uid)

```
(SELECT DISTINCT n2.nid
  FROM node n2
  LEFT JOIN applicationsTable ON n2.nid = applicationsTable.nid
   WHERE n2.status = '1'
    AND n2.type = 'job'
    AND n.nid= n2.nid
    AND applicationsTable.uid ='999');
```

Oddly enough my query doesn't work as a straight db call so feel free to correct me on that too :P

Answer (score 1):

In settings of the User ID contextual filter, you can exclude this argument/contextual-filter. Expand the last field-set and you'll see it. isn't it what you need to do ?